# How to enable Arabic in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, arabic

Can I know how to enable arabic in Silverlight?? I have a requirement in which user can select whether they would like to type in English or Arabic and based on their selection the language must change. Can anyone pls help me out?? Thank you.

Comment: Accept some answer, 0% rate looks sad.

Comment: Check this post

[silverlight-5-input-language-override-issue-in-chrome-firefox][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901530/silverlight-5-input-language-override-issue-in-chrome-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight 4 (The latest version at this time) now supports Bi-Directional text, Right-to-Left and complex scripts such as Arabic, Hebrew and 31 new languages.
http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight-4/

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight 4 supports Arabic, RTL and bi-directional text. You do not need to do anything within your application to support this! To enter Arabic text, your user simply needs to select an Arabic keyboard. Instructions for selecting keyboards are given here:

[How to change keyboard language in Windows](http://www.conversationexchange.com/resources/keyboard-language.php)