# Silverlight 5 input language override issue in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer, google-chrome, localization, arabic

Working on a fairly large Silverlight project I have an issue with Chrome/Firefox not respecting the input language set by the user.

In IE, if I change the keyboard language to Arabic, the input is in Arabic. If I do this while running the Silverlight application in Chrome/Firefox, then it doesn't matter what keyboard settings I have, the input is still in English.

Is there something way to override the input language which I am not seeing? I ask because if I create a new SL project with only a `TextBox` on the form, then all behaviour is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `param name="windowless" value="true"` in your Silverlight param configuration? If yes, then remove this line and try again.

The property `windowless` has a problem with Chrome and Firefox with characters with accents, still I could not solve the problem.